# Strange name of files creating in android

Tags: android, eclipse

i am using following code

```
                    Integer val = myReceipt.receiptId ;
                    String fileName = "image" + "_" + title.getText().toString()+"_" + val.toString(); 
                    photo = this.createTemporaryFile(fileName, ".jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                    uriOfPhoto = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CAMERA_SELECT);
                  }
                }


            private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception
            {
                File tempDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Catch All Keeper/Receipts");
                if(!tempDir.exists())
                {
                    tempDir.mkdir();
                }
                tempDir.canWrite();
                return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
            }
        });
```

Now, it should give name to file `image_title_val` but it gives a strange name as `image_title_(some random numbers).jpg`

Can anyone tell what is the problem here?

Comment: what is myReceipt.receiptId ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using File.createTempFile to get a unique name. That function assigns the random numbers you see. The fileName string passed in parameter part is used as a prefix to generate the temporary file name.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you want a unique file name than your code is correct and no fix is need. If you are sure that format image_title_val is unique than don't call createTempFile anymore. Having a valid name you can create a new file like this: new File(tempDir, part + ext).createNewFile();